# Script/scheduled task to clean up Dowloads folder (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7

My downloads folder is my primary connection to the internet (and thus the world), and has rapidly become a virtual junk drawer.  I imagine I'm not alone here.

What I'd like to do is have some sort of a script that

-creates a new folder (named YYYY_MM Archive so it sorts nicely)

-takes everything* inside of the Downloads folder (for the current user)

-moves it to the new folder

and have this run once/month.

*(excluding previous archives)

This strikes me as the type of thing
Saw some [answers](https://superuser.com/questions/239405/script-to-clean-up-folder-names) on related questions that seemed to suggest that this is an eminently doable task in PowerShell.  Is it?  I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

My answer isn't a DIY solution using built in windows tools and the scheduler.

However, I'm a big fan of SyncBackSE by http://2brightsparks.com.  I'm not affilited with them in any way, but their software works well for me to backup folders on a schedule, and is loaded with options.

A actually use it in part of my software build processes where I launch a SyncBackSE profile via cmd line that does the file backup and moving that I need.

You can set up an automated backup job, which will move instead of copy, and you can use variables tp create folder names like you're asking to do.

With the vast number of options, you can customize the job to move the files only if they're older than x, or only move certain types of files by using filters, etc. Worth looking into and not expensive, and you'll also end up with a very versitile backup program that can copy to other folders on your network, or even to an FTP server.