# Clean up filenames using data from a text file

Tags: script, perl, rename

I need to clean up a bunch of folder file names. Possibly even the file titles as well. I was currently using [this Perl script to do so](https://superuser.com/questions/239405/script-to-clean-up-folder-names)  but I ran into some problems.

1. If the file name already has parenthesis around the year, it adds another set.
2. I would like to also use a text file to remove common "signatures" in titles as well, ex. `This.Movie.Blah.(2012) [1080p] MP4`.

   Currently the script I have replaces the `.` with a space as intended and adds `(xxxx)` around the year. Running the script the outcome would be `This Movie Blah ((2012)) [1080p] MP4`.

Also I would like remove the "signatures" that match a text files values (lined, not CSV) from the file name so `This.Movie.Blah.(2012) [1080p] MP4` would return `This Movie Blah (2012)`

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Copy;

my $oldname;

opendir(my $d, ".") or die $!;
while(readdir $d) {
    if (-d $_ and $_ ne "." and $_ ne "..")
    {
        $oldname = $_;
        $_ =~ s/\./ /g;
        $_ =~ s/(\d{4})/($1)/g;
        move($oldname,$_);
    }
    }
closedir $d;
```

I had just started trying to learn Perl today as one of my first programming languages so I am relatively new to this language.

Answer (score 0):

As a question of regular expressions (searching text for patterns and doing replacements based on them), this is not hard; I’m surprised that there are no answers after 15 hours.  I’m not as experienced in Perl as I’d like to be, but a straightforward approach to the year-in-parentheses problem is simply to detect it afterwards and fix it then:

```
        $_ =~ s/(\d{4})/($1)/g;
        $_ =~ s/(\((\d{4})\))/$1/g;
```

The second statement looks for `((2012))` and returns the middle six characters; i.e., the `(2012)`.  As to “common signatures”, how about

```
        $_ =~ s/ \[1080p\] MP4$//;
```

?   (Use `\[` and `\]` to prevent `[…]` from being interpreted as a range, and `$` to refer to the end of the string.